# Declaration and initialization of global variable

Tags: c++

Maybe it is base knowledge, I am apologize.

I have a header file CTemp.h, with namespace CTemp:

```
namespace CTemp
{
    bool bFlag;

};

#ifndef _CTEMP
#define _CTEMP
bool CTemp::bFlag = true;

#endif
```

and if I include CTemp.h to my cpp file and try to use CTemp::bFlag

```
bool bb = CTemp::bFlag;
```

the compiler throw error "redefinition"

I surely know, that I should to put initialization to a .cpp file, but I find some way, to solve it only with .h file. Because I don't want to add the .cpp file to my project.
I thought, I could solve it with preprocessor directives #ifdef....

Thanks for advice.

Comment: why is the declaration outside of the include guards?

Comment: You can use `extern bool bFlag` in your H file (declaration), and `bool bFlag = true;` in the CPP (definition). However - using global variables is usually not a good idea (to say the least).

Comment: Because both `bool bFlag;` and `bool CTemp::bFlag = true;` are definitions.

Comment: Dupe: [How can I call a method of a variable, which contains in a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569547/how-can-i-call-a-method-of-a-variable-which-contains-in-a-namespace/72569621#72569621) and [Global Constants in .h included in multiple c++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72355478/global-constants-in-h-included-in-multiple-c-project/72357013#72357013)

Answer (score 3):

In the header file you should only *declare* the variable:

```
#ifndef CTEMP_H
#define CTEMP_H

namespace CTemp
{
    extern bool bFlag;  // Need extern to only declare the variable
}

#endif // CTEMP_H
```

Then in one single source file you define the variable with its initialization:

```
#include "ctemp.h"

bool CTemp::bFlag = true;
```

---

Alternatively define the variable as *inline*:

```
#ifndef CTEMP_H
#define CTEMP_H

namespace CTemp
{
    inline bool bFlag = true;
}

#endif // CTEMP_H
```

Now you should *not* define the variable in a source file.

Comment: But inline bFlag will not be global, isn't it?

Comment: @MichalHadraba Who said that? With C++17, you can use `inline` and `bFlag` will still be global as shown in this answer. Also the exact same thing is explained here: [How can I call a method of a variable, which contains in a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72569621/12002570) in the dupe. See *method 2* of the above linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72569621/12002570).

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that both `bool bFlag` and `bool CTemp::bFlag = true;` are definitions. In other words, you're defining `bFlag` for the second time when you wrote: `bool bFlag = true;`.

```
namespace CTemp
{
    bool bFlag;  //this is a definition for the first time

};

#ifndef _CTEMP
#define _CTEMP
bool CTemp::bFlag = true;  //this is also a definition but for the second time and hence the error
```

##### Solution

To solve this you can use the `extern` keyword:

**someheader.h**

```
#ifndef _CTEMP
#define _CTEMP
namespace CTemp
{
    extern bool bFlag; //this is a declaration and not a definition

};
#endif
```

**somesource.cpp**

```
#include "someheader.h"
bool CTemp::bFlag = true; //this is a definition
```